# Formulario con PHP y mysql

Tags: php, html

No tengo mucha experiencia con php y tengo en problema con un formulario. Tengo que enviar los datos a una base de datos, localhost, y no me funciona. No me da ningun error en la consola. Agrego bien los datos y al darle a enviar, me lleva a una página en blanco. Quizá el error esta en los checkboxs, no se si he recogido bien el valor.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.
Archivo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container-header">
      <img class='img-header' src="./img/logo.png" />
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h1>AUTORITZACIÓ DRETS D’IMATGE</h1>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="container-form">
      <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div>
          <p>En/na
            <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Nom i cognoms">
            , amb document d’identificació
            <input type="text" name="txtDni" id="txtDni" placeholder="DNI/NIE">
            com millor procedeixi,
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-check">
          <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check1">Aceptar
          <br>
          <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check2">Denegar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-text">
      <p>
        Tanmateix se m’informa del dret a presentar una reclamació davant l’Agencia Española de Protección de Datos i de
        l’Autoritat Catalana de Protecció de Dades.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/resilis.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/astres.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/gentis.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/infanciaYFamilia.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/fasi.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/utopia.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/el7.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/accionat.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/einaActiva.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/idaria.png" />
    <img class='img-aside' src="./img/plataforma.png" />
  </aside>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <footer>
    <div class="container-footer">
      <div class="container-fecha">
        <div>
          <label>Nom i cognoms</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombreCompleto" id="nombreCompleto" placeholder="Nom i gognoms">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="cont-fecha">
          <label>Data</label>
          <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" placeholder="dia/mes/any">
        </div>
        <div class="cont-submit">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cont-icons">
        <div class="cont-plat">
          <div>
            <p>PLATAFORMA EDUCATIVA</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a class='enlace' href="www.plataformaeducativa.org">www.plataformaeducativa.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont-calidad">
          <div>
            <img class="img-icons2" src="./img/tuvr.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img class="img-icons" src="./img/judilex.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img class="img-icons3" src="./img/nueveR.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

El archivo PHP:

```
 <?php
 
// database connection code
 
// $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuariodelabasededatos', 'passworddelabasededatos','basededatos');
 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','privacidadImagen');
 
// get the post records
 
$txtNombre = $_POST['txtNombre'];
 
$txtDni = $_POST['txtDni'];
 
$nombreCompleto = $_POST['nombreCompleto'];

$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

if ($_POST['check1']!=null){
   $check=true;
}if ($_POST['check2']!=null){
  $check=false;
}
 
// database insert SQL code
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO db_privacidad (id, nombre, dni, nombreCompleto, fecha, aceptacion) VALUES ('0', '$txtNombre', '$txtDni', '$nombreCompleto', '$fecha', '$check')";
// insert in database
 
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 
if($rs)
 
{
 
echo "Formulario enviado con éxito.";
 
}
 
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy viendo que la etiqueta de cierre del form esta fuera de su sitio. Pero tengo 2 formularios, uno arriba (nombre, dni y check) y otro abajo (nombre y fecha) y solo un botón. No se muy bien como tendría que estructurar eso. Igual ahi esta el fallo

Comment: ¿Inserta los datos en tu tabla de base de datos?

Comment: No, no inserta nada, página en blanco y ningun error donde agarrarme.

Comment: Podrias poner `var_dump($rs)` en lugar de `echo "formulario enviado"` tal vez así podrias ver algun mensaje de error

Comment: Consegui solucionarlo, no se muy bien como. Ahora cuando vea el error, lo subire. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No uses checkbox o te dará un dolor de cabeza manejarlo. Usa Radios

```
<input class="check" type="radio" name="check" value="1">Aceptar
<br>
<input class="check" type="radio" name="check" value="0">Denegar
```

Y en el PHP solo necesitas esto

```
$check = $_POST['check'];
```

Por cierto ya lo probé y funciona perfecto...

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los que intentaron ayudarme, al final el código estaba correcto, era por un archivo que tenía de más en el proyecto y que hacía que no se me abriera el archivo correcto.

Comment: Pueda que si, pero usar checkbox es un error, se pueden seleccionar ambas opciones y eso no es correcto. Use radios y eso guardará en su DB el valor real que elija el usuario.